# Showing Time in Date Picker Set The Maximum time And Minimum time

Tags: ios, objective-c

Any One pls Solve the Issues I got The Date And Time MATCHDATE from web service but i Need to edit the Time Alone in Date Picker ...And I need To set the Maximum Time And Minimum Time.

**Here Is my Code**

```
- (IBAction)EndBreak_btn:(id)sender {


  //  _text_EndBreak.text=_MATCHDATE;
    [_datePicker_View setHidden:NO];
    [_date_picker setHidden:YES];
     [_date_picker1 setHidden:NO];
    _date_picker1.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [_date_picker1 addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(BreakEnd:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

-(void)BreakEnd:(id)sender
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:_MATCHDATE];
      [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
    [_date_picker1 setDate:date];
   //[_date_picker1 setMinimumDate:date];


    NSString *Time = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    BREAKENDTIME =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@" ,[_text_EndBreak text],Time];

}
```

i show the Time alone in Time Picker But When I select th time It getting Crashed because of the MatchDate String is Nill ...I can't convert the Time Alone From The MatchDateString
Thanks In Advance

Comment: where u get the _MATCHDATE, can  u show the result of this

Comment: are you there .....

Comment: NSDictionary*test3=[temp3 objectAtIndex:l];
                NSString* MatchDate =[test3 objectForKey:@"MatchDate"]; MatchDate 2016-06-25 12:00:00 i got the Match Date From web service

Comment: Anbu Bro R u there

Comment: Any one there to solve my issues

Comment: yes , what the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                            2016-06-25 12:00:00
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:_MATCHDATE];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];

// for minimum date
[_date_picker1 setMinimumDate:date];

// for maximumDate
int daysToAdd = 2;
NSDate *newDate1 = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];

 [_date_picker1 setMaximumDate:newDate1];



 NSString *Time = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
BREAKENDTIME =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@" ,[_text_EndBreak text],Time];
```

Comment: i ask that i need to edit time alone in date picker other wise the date picker Shows minimum date and maximum date   the minimum date was Match Date and Maximum date should be adding 2 days from The MatchDate

Comment: from web service date adding 2 days it will shows the date picker ?

Comment: based on condition you need to split , I think now you got it the idea , correct

Comment: I dont knw ur project sister, but I caluculate based on `_MATCHDATE`

Comment: ya i got the idea but my doubt is i need to show the date between web service date and adding 5 days from the Webservice date is thats possible in date picker

Comment: i got the match date from web service but its dynamically change bro...and

Comment: based on the date it is dynamically chnage , one question is there any difference between `_MATCHDATE` and `web service date`

Comment: no actually i mean that i got the date from web service

Comment: can u call my no 9790811202

Comment: my doubt is the picker will show from match date to newDate1 ?